# EF4 - foreign key pointing to multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following 3 tables:

```
public class Project
{
    // other fields...

    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Experiment
{
    // other fields...

    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    // ...
}
```

If I create this structure, EF will create the table *Attachments* with two columns: **ProjectId** and **ExperimentId**.

How can I tell EF that I the relationships Experiment->Attachment and Project->Attachment must "share" the same key on Attachment?

Something like:

```
public class Attachment
{
    // other fields...

    // can be a Guid from either Experiment or Project
    public Guid BelongingModelId { get; set; }

    // I will set this manually in order to know from which table the Guid is coming
    public String BelongingModelType { get; set; }
}
```

Is possible to do something like this?

I tried in the DbContext / OnModelCreating but I found no solutions.

Thanks,
Guido

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make Project and Experiment inherit from a base class.

```
public class Model
{
    // other common fields...

    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Project : Model
{
    // project fields...     
}

public class Experiment : Model
{
    // experiment fields...
}

public class Attachment
{
    // other fields...

    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

You will have to do some casting to figure out what Model is for a given attachment.

```
var project = attachment.Model as Project;
if (project != null)
{
    // you have a project
}
var experiment = attachment.Model as Experiment;
if (project != null)
{
    // you have an experiment
}
```

Or you can tell EF to only give you attachments for a certain type of Model.

```
var attachments = context.Attachments.Where(a => a.Model is Project);
```